# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()

Tags: php

SO I'm getting this error when trying to upload an image.

the code part is here

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES["site_logo"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_PNG)
        {
            adminFunctions::setError('Logo does not appear to be a PNG image. Please check and try again.');
        }
```

I tried to add this setting to php.ini and checked that it's enabled

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=exif.so
extension=php_exif.dll
```

and the strange that it's working on my localhost but online it's giving that error!

Comment: `.so`'s is unix, `.dll`'s is windows.. I not sure your config would work

Comment: Found the problem, the host wasn't supporting exif so I contacted them and they enabled it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the host and they enabled exif for the server even I inserted it in the php.ini it wasn't installed on the server itself.